# Ordenar un select alfabéticamente con los datos obtenidos de un Json

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Estoy tratando de hacer una aplicación en php que tiene tres selects. En el primero cargamos la lista de idiomas que tenemos en la base de datos. Una vez que se ha seleccionado el idioma, se hace una consulta para obtener un `json` que devuelve un `array` con el par id-nombre de los países.

En la consulta en la base de datos pedimos que se ordene por nombre. Y dicho `json` se obtiene correctamente ordenado,

EDITO: el Json en formato texto seria este:

```
{"144":"Afganist\u00e1n","114":"Albania","18":"Alemania","98":"Algeria","145":"Andorra","119":"Angola","4":"Anguilla","147":"Antigua y Barbuda","207":"Antillas Holandesas","91":"Arabia Saudita","5":"Argentina","6":"Armenia","142":"Aruba","1":"Australia","2":"Austria","3":"Azerbaiy\u00e1n","80":"Bahamas","127":"Bahrein","149":"Bangladesh","128":"Barbados","9":"B\u00e9lgica","8":"Belice","151":"Ben\u00edn","10":"Bermudas","7":"Bielorrusia","123":"Bolivia","79":"Bosnia y Herzegovina","100":"Botsuana","12":"Brasil","155":"Brun\u00e9i","11":"Bulgaria","156":"Burkina Faso","157":"Burundi","152":"But\u00e1n","159":"Cabo Verde","158":"Camboya","31":"Camer\u00fan","32":"Canad\u00e1","82":"Colombia","164":"Comores","112":"Congo (Brazzaville)","165":"Congo (Kinshasa)","166":"Cook, Islas","84":"Corea del Norte","69":"Corea del Sur","168":"Costa de Marfil","36":"Costa Rica","71":"Croacia","113":"Cuba","130":"Chad","81":"Chile","35":"China","33":"Chipre","22":"Dinamarca","169":"Djibouti, Yibuti","103":"Ecuador","23":"Egipto","51":"El Salvador","93":"Emiratos \u00e1rabes Unidos","173":"Eritrea","52":"Eslovaquia","53":"Eslovenia","28":"Espa\u00f1a","55":"Estados Unidos","68":"Estonia","121":"Etiop\u00eda","175":"Feroe, Islas","90":"Filipinas","63":"Finlandia","176":"Fiyi","64":"Francia","180":"Gab\u00f3n","181":"Gambia","21":"Georgia","105":"Ghana","143":"Gibraltar","184":"Granada","20":"Grecia","94":"Groenlandia","17":"Guadalupe","185":"Guatemala","186":"Guernsey","187":"Guinea","172":"Guinea Ecuatorial","188":"Guinea-Bissau","189":"Guyana","16":"Haiti","137":"Honduras","73":"Hong Kong","14":"Hungr\u00eda","25":"India","74":"Indonesia","140":"Irak","26":"Ir\u00e1n","27":"Irlanda","215":"Isla Pitcairn","83":"Islandia","228":"Islas Salom\u00f3n","58":"Islas Turcas y Caicos","154":"Islas Virgenes Brit\u00e1nicas","24":"Israel","29":"Italia","132":"Jamaica","70":"Jap\u00f3n","193":"Jersey","75":"Jordania","30":"Kazajst\u00e1n","97":"Kenia","34":"Kirguist\u00e1n","195":"Kiribati","37":"Kuwait","196":"Laos","197":"Lesotho","38":"Letonia","99":"L\u00edbano","198":"Liberia","39":"Libia","126":"Liechtenstein","40":"Lituania","41":"Luxemburgo","85":"Macedonia","134":"Madagascar","76":"Malasia","125":"Malawi","200":"Maldivas","133":"Mal\u00ed","86":"Malta","131":"Man, Isla de","104":"Marruecos","201":"Martinica","202":"Mauricio","108":"Mauritania","42":"M\u00e9xico","43":"Moldavia","44":"M\u00f3naco","139":"Mongolia","117":"Mozambique","205":"Myanmar","102":"Namibia","206":"Nauru","107":"Nepal","209":"Nicaragua","210":"N\u00edger","115":"Nigeria","212":"Norfolk Island","46":"Noruega","208":"Nueva Caledonia","45":"Nueva Zelanda","213":"Om\u00e1n","19":"Pa\u00edses Bajos, Holanda","87":"Pakist\u00e1n","124":"Panam\u00e1","88":"Pap\u00faa-Nueva Guinea","110":"Paraguay","89":"Per\u00fa","178":"Polinesia Francesa","47":"Polonia","48":"Portugal","246":"Puerto Rico","216":"Qatar","13":"Reino Unido","65":"Rep\u00fablica Checa","138":"Rep\u00fablica Dominicana","49":"Reuni\u00f3n","217":"Ruanda","72":"Ruman\u00eda","50":"Rusia","242":"S\u00e1hara Occidental","223":"Samoa","219":"San Cristobal y Nevis","224":"San Marino","221":"San Pedro y Miquel\u00f3n","225":"San Tom\u00e9 y Pr\u00edncipe","222":"San Vincente y Granadinas","218":"Santa Elena","220":"Santa Luc\u00eda","135":"Senegal","226":"Serbia y Montenegro","109":"Seychelles","227":"Sierra Leona","77":"Singapur","106":"Siria","229":"Somalia","120":"Sri Lanka","141":"Sud\u00e1frica","232":"Sud\u00e1n","67":"Suecia","66":"Suiza","54":"Surinam","234":"Swazilandia","56":"Tadjikistan","92":"Tailandia","78":"Taiwan","101":"Tanzania","171":"Timor Oriental","136":"Togo","235":"Tokelau","236":"Tonga","237":"Trinidad y Tobago","122":"T\u00fanez","57":"Turkmenistan","59":"Turqu\u00eda","239":"Tuvalu","62":"Ucrania","60":"Uganda","111":"Uruguay","61":"Uzbekist\u00e1n","240":"Vanuatu","95":"Venezuela","15":"Vietnam","241":"Wallis y Futuna","243":"Yemen","116":"Zambia","96":"Zimbabwe"}
```

Pero a la hora de mostrarlo en el `select`, no lo muestra ordenado alfabéticamente, sino por el valor id, tal como muestra la imagen:

[image: Resultado en la web]

Por mas vuelta que le doy al código, no encuentro una solución.... el código del `select` es el siguiente:

```
<div class="selector-pais">
        País:
        <select></select>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $(".selector-idioma select").change(function() {
                    $(".selector-pais select").empty();
                    $.getJSON('getPaises.php?idioma='+$(".selector-idioma select").val(),function(data){
                        $.each(data, function(id,value){
                            $(".selector-pais select").append('<option value="'+id+'">'+value+'</option>');
                        });
                    });
                });
            });
        </script>
    </div>
```

Y el de `getPaises` es:

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'paises');

$mysqli->set_charset("utf8");

$query = "SELECT idPais, nombre FROM traduccion WHERE idIdioma=".$_REQUEST["idioma"]." ORDER BY nombre";
$result = $mysqli->query($query);
$paises = array();
while ($fila = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    $paises[$fila['idPais']] = $fila['nombre'];
}
print_r(json_encode($paises));

mysqli_free_result($result);
mysqli_close($mysqli);
```

¿Alguna posible solución?

Comment: La pregunta está bien planteada, pero deberías poner el JSON recibido como texto, la captura de pantalla no es fácil de leer y no permite copiar un trozo a las respuestas

Comment: Perdona.... tienes razon. Lo edito

Comment: Muchas gracias. Ya logre arreglarlo con un cambio de enfoque

Comment: Recuerda marcar una respuesta como aceptada si te fue de utilidad. Un saludo

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tienes varias opciones:

Que PHP te devuelva un array de la forma:

```
[ { "id": <id_pais> , "nombre": "<nombre_pais>" },
  { "id": <id_pais> , "nombre": "<nombre_pais>" },
  { "id": <id_pais> , "nombre": "<nombre_pais>" },
  ...
]
```

Y entonces ordenarlo, ya sea con PHP o con javascript:

```js
 const paises= [ { "id": 1 , "nombre": "España" },
      { "id": 2 , "nombre": "Andorra" },
      { "id": 3 , "nombre": "Portugal" }
    ]
    
paises.sort((a,b) => a.nombre < b.nombre ? -1 : +(a.nombre > b.nombre))

console.log(paises);
```

Que Javascript transforme ese objeto en el array previo y lo ordene:

```js
const paises={
  1: 'España',
  2: 'Andorra',
  35:'Portugal'
}

const array=[];

for (let i in paises) {
  array.push({ id: i, nombre: paises[i]});
}

console.log(array);

array.sort((a,b) => a.nombre < b.nombre ? -1 : +(a.nombre > b.nombre));

console.log(array.map(a=>a.nombre));
```

Answer (score 5):

Hace poco hice algo parecido con el [Array.prototipe](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) `sort`. La ordenación se hace a posteriori y por texto:

```
function sortDropDownListByText(selectId) {
     //Separo la primera opción del select (vacío) porque no quiero ordenarla
    var foption = $('#' + selectId + ' option:first');
    //Ordeno todas menos la primera (Si el texto de a y el de b son iguales no se hace nada, si el de a es menor que el de b es porque tiene que ir en un índice anterior (en la documentación indicada se explican todos los casos posibles de la compareFunction())
    var soptions = $('#' + selectId + ' option:not(:first)').sort(function (a, b) {
        return a.text == b.text ? 0 : a.text < b.text ? -1 : 1
    });
    //Reasigno al select los valores ordenados y le añado antes la primera opción
    $('#' + selectId).html(soptions).prepend(foption);

};
```

Aquí te dejo un ejemplo:

```js
    var foption = $('#selectPais option:first');
    var soptions = $('#selectPais option:not(:first)').sort(function (a, b) {
        return a.text == b.text ? 0 : a.text < b.text ? -1 : 1
    });
    $('#selectPais').html(soptions).prepend(foption);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
Select sin ordenar
</div>
<select id="selectPaisSinOrdenar" aria-required="true" style="width: 93%;" required=""><option value=""><option value="SD">SUDÁN</option><option value="SE">SUECIA</option><option value="CH">SUIZA (INCLUIDOS EL TERRITORIO ALEMáN DE BüSINGEN Y E1 MUNICIPIO</option><option value="SR">SURINAM</option><option value="TH">TAILANDIA</option><option value="TW">TAIWAN</option><option value="TZ">TANZANIA (REPÚBLICA UNIDA DE) (TANGANICA E ISLAS DE ZANZíBAR Y PEMBA)</option><option value="TJ">TAYIKISTÁN</option><option value="PS">TERRITORIO PALESTINO OCUPADO</option></option><option value="AF">AFGANISTAN</option><option value="AL">ALBANIA</option><option value="DE">ALEMANIA (INCLUIDA LA ISLA DE HELGOLAND)</option><option value="AD">ANDORRA</option><option value="AO">ANGOLA (INCLUIDO CABINDA)</option><option value="AI">ANGUILA</option><option value="AG">ANTIGUA Y BARBUDA</option><option value="AN">ANTILLAS NEERLANDESAS (CURAçAO, BONAIRE, SAN EUSTAQUIO, SABA Y LA PARTE MER</option><option value="AQ">ANTÁRTIDA</option><option value="SA">ARABIA SAUDI</option><option value="DZ">ARGELIA</option><option value="AR">ARGENTINA</option><option value="AM">ARMENIA</option><option value="AW">ARUBA</option><option value="AU">AUSTRALIA</option><option value="AT">AUSTRIA</option><option value="AZ">AZERBAIYÁN</option><option value="BS">BAHAMAS</option><option value="BH">BAHRÉIN</option><option value="XB">BANCO CENTRAL EUROPEO</option><option value="BD">BANGLADESH</option><option value="BB">BARBADOS</option><option value="BZ">BELICE</option><option value="BJ">BENÍN</option><option value="BM">BERMUDAS</option><option value="BY">BIELORRUSIA (BELARÚS)</option><option value="BO">BOLIVIA</option><option value="BA">BOSNIA-HERZEGOVINA</option><option value="BW">BOTSUANA</option><option value="BV">BOUVET, ISLA</option><option value="BR">BRASIL</option><option value="BN">BRUNÉI (BRUNÉI DARUSSALAM)</option><option value="BG">BULGARIA</option><option value="BF">BURKINA FASO (ALTO VOLTA)</option><option value="BI">BURUNDI</option><option value="BT">BUTÁN</option><option value="BE">BÉLGICA</option><option value="CV">CABO VERDE, REPÚBLICA DE</option><option value="KY">CAIMÁN, ISLAS</option><option value="KH">CAMBOYA</option><option value="CM">CAMERÚN</option><option value="CA">CANADÁ</option><option value="CF">CENTROAFRICANA, REPÚBLICA</option><option value="TD">CHAD</option><option value="CZ">CHECA, REPÚBLICA</option><option value="CL">CHILE</option><option value="CN">CHINA</option><option value="CY">CHIPRE</option><option value="CC">COCOS, ISLA DE (KEELING)</option><option value="CO">COLOMBIA</option><option value="KM">COMORAS (GRAN COMORA, ANJOUAN Y MOHéLI)</option><option value="CG">CONGO</option><option value="CD">CONGO, REPÚBLICA DEMOCRÁTICA DEL (ZAIRE)</option><option value="CK">COOK, ISLAS</option><option value="KP">COREA DEL NORTE (REPúBLICA POPULAR DEMOCRáTICA DE COREA)</option><option value="KR">COREA DEL SUR (REPúBLICA DE COREA)</option><option value="CI">COSTA DE MARFIL</option><option value="CR">COSTA RICA</option><option value="HR">CROACIA</option><option value="CU">CUBA</option><option value="DK">DINAMARCA</option><option value="DM">DOMINICA</option><option value="DO">DOMINICANA, REPÚBLICA</option><option value="EC">ECUADOR (INCLUIDAS LAS ISLAS GALáPAGOS)</option><option value="EG">EGIPTO</option><option value="AE">EMIRATOS ÁRABES UNIDOS (ABU DABI, DUBAI, SHARYA, AYMAN,</option><option value="ER">ERITREA</option><option value="SK">ESLOVAQUIA</option><option value="SI">ESLOVENIA</option><option value="ES">ESPAÑA</option><option value="US">ESTADOS UNIDOS DE AMÉRICA</option><option value="EE">ESTONIA</option><option value="ET">ETIOPÍA</option><option value="FO">FEROE, ISLAS</option><option value="PH">FILIPINAS</option><option value="FI">FINLANDIA (INCLUIDAS LAS ISLAS ALAND)</option><option value="FJ">FIYI</option><option value="FR">FRANCIA (INCLUIDOS LOS DEPARTAMENTOS FRANCESES DE ULTRAMAR:</option><option value="GA">GABÓN</option><option value="GM">GAMBIA</option><option value="GE">GEORGIA</option><option value="GS">GEORGIA DEL SUR Y LAS ISLAS SANDWICH DEL SUR</option><option value="GH">GHANA</option><option value="GI">GIBRALTAR</option><option value="GD">GRANADA (INCLUIDAS LAS ISLAS GRANADINAS DEL SUR)</option><option value="GR">GRECIA</option><option value="GL">GROENLANDIA</option><option value="GU">GUAM</option><option value="GT">GUATEMALA</option><option value="GG">GUERNESEY (ISLA ANGLONORMANDA DEL CANAL)</option><option value="GN">GUINEA</option><option value="GQ">GUINEA ECUATORIAL</option><option value="GW">GUINEA-BISSAU</option><option value="GY">GUYANA</option><option value="HT">HAITÍ</option><option value="HM">HEARD Y MCDONALD, ISLAS</option><option value="HN">HONDURAS (INCLUIDAS ISLAS DEL CISNE)</option><option value="HK">HONG-KONG</option><option value="HU">HUNGRIA</option><option value="IN">INDIA</option><option value="ID">INDONESIA</option><option value="XU">INSTITUCIONES DE LA UNIÓN EUROPEA</option><option value="IQ">IRAQ</option><option value="IE">IRLANDA</option><option value="IR">IRÁN</option><option value="IM">ISLA DE MAN</option><option value="IS">ISLANDIA</option><option value="IL">ISRAEL</option><option value="IT">ITALIA (INCLUIDO LIVIGNO)</option><option value="JM">JAMAICA</option><option value="JP">JAPÓN</option><option value="JE">JERSEY (ISLA ANGLONORMANDA DEL CANAI)</option><option value="JO">JORDANIA</option><option value="KZ">KAZAJSTÁN</option><option value="KE">KENIA</option><option value="KG">KIRGUISTÁN</option><option value="KI">KIRIBATI</option><option value="KW">KUWAIT</option><option value="LA">LAOS (LAO)</option><option value="LS">LESOTHO</option><option value="LV">LETONIA</option><option value="LR">LIBERIA</option><option value="LY">LIBIA</option><option value="LI">LIECHTENSTEIN</option><option value="LT">LITUANIA</option><option value="LU">LUXEMBURGO</option><option value="XG">LUXEMBURGO [POR LO QUE RESPECTA A LAS RENTAS PERCIBIDAS POR LAS SOCIEDADES</option><option value="LB">LÍBANO</option><option value="MO">MACAO</option><option value="MK">MACEDONIA (ANTIGUA REPúBLICA YUGOSLAVA)</option><option value="MG">MADAGASCAR</option><option value="MY">MALASIA (MALASIA PENINSULAR Y MALASIA ORIENTAL: SARAWAK, UMM AL-QAIWAIN, RA</option><option value="MW">MALAWI</option><option value="MV">MALDIVAS</option><option value="ML">MALI</option><option value="MT">MALTA (INCLUIDOS GOZO Y COMINO)</option><option value="FK">MALVINAS, ISLAS (FALKLANDS)</option><option value="MP">MARIANAS DEL NORTE, ISLAS</option><option value="MA">MARRUECOS</option><option value="MH">MARSHALL, ISLAS</option><option value="MU">MAURICIO [ISLAS MAURICIO, ISLAS RODRIGUES, ISLAS AGALEGA Y CARGADOS, CARAJO</option><option value="MR">MAURITANIA</option><option value="YT">MAYOTTE (GRAN TIERRA Y PAMANDZI)</option><option value="UM">MENORES ALEJADAS DE LOS EE.UU., ISLAS (BAKER, HOWLAND, JARVIS, JOHSTON, KIN</option><option value="MX">MEXICO</option><option value="MD">MOLDAVIA</option><option value="MN">MONGOLIA</option><option value="ME">MONTENEGRO</option><option value="MS">MONTSERRAT</option><option value="MZ">MOZAMBIQUE</option><option value="XN">ORGANISMOS INTERNACIONALES DISTINTOS DE LAS INSTITUCIONES DE LA UNIÓN EUROP</option><option value="QU">OTROS PAÍSES O TERRITORIOS NO RELACIONADOS</option><option value="PK">PAKISTÁN</option><option value="PW">PALAU</option><option value="PA">PANAMÁ (INCLUIDA LA ANTIGUA ZONA DEL CANAL)</option><option value="MM">MYANMAR (ANTIGUA BIRMANIA)</option><option value="MC">MÓNACO</option><option value="NA">NAMIBIA</option><option value="NR">NAURU</option><option value="CX">NAVIDAD, ISLA</option><option value="NP">NEPAL</option><option value="NI">NICARAGUA (INCLUIDAS LAS ISLAS DEL MAíZ)</option><option value="NG">NIGERIA</option><option value="NU">NIUE, ISLA</option><option value="NF">NORFOLK, ISLA</option><option value="NO">NORUEGA (INCLUIDAS LAS ISLAS LEALTAD: MARé, LIFOU Y OUVéA)</option><option value="NC">NUEVA CALEDONIA (INCLUIDAS LAS ISLAS LEALTAD: MARé, LIFOU Y OUVéA)</option><option value="NZ">NUEVA ZELANDA</option><option value="NE">NÍGER</option><option value="IO">OCÉANO INDICO, TERRITORIO BRITÁNICO DEL (ARCHIPIéLAGO  DE CHAGOS)</option><option value="OM">OMÁN</option><option value="XN">ORGANISMOS INTERNACIONALES DISTINTOS DE LAS INSTITUCIONES DE LA UNIÓN EUROP</option><option value="QU">OTROS PAÍSES O TERRITORIOS NO RELACIONADOS</option><option value="PK">PAKISTÁN</option><option value="PW">PALAU</option><option value="PA">PANAMÁ (INCLUIDA LA ANTIGUA ZONA DEL CANAL)</option></select>
<div>
Select ordenado
</div>
<select id="selectPais" aria-required="true" style="width: 93%;" required=""><option value=""><option value="SD">SUDÁN</option><option value="SE">SUECIA</option><option value="CH">SUIZA (INCLUIDOS EL TERRITORIO ALEMáN DE BüSINGEN Y E1 MUNICIPIO</option><option value="SR">SURINAM</option><option value="TH">TAILANDIA</option><option value="TW">TAIWAN</option><option value="TZ">TANZANIA (REPÚBLICA UNIDA DE) (TANGANICA E ISLAS DE ZANZíBAR Y PEMBA)</option><option value="TJ">TAYIKISTÁN</option><option value="PS">TERRITORIO PALESTINO OCUPADO</option></option><option value="AF">AFGANISTAN</option><option value="AL">ALBANIA</option><option value="DE">ALEMANIA (INCLUIDA LA ISLA DE HELGOLAND)</option><option value="AD">ANDORRA</option><option value="AO">ANGOLA (INCLUIDO CABINDA)</option><option value="AI">ANGUILA</option><option value="AG">ANTIGUA Y BARBUDA</option><option value="AN">ANTILLAS NEERLANDESAS (CURAçAO, BONAIRE, SAN EUSTAQUIO, SABA Y LA PARTE MER</option><option value="AQ">ANTÁRTIDA</option><option value="SA">ARABIA SAUDI</option><option value="DZ">ARGELIA</option><option value="AR">ARGENTINA</option><option value="AM">ARMENIA</option><option value="AW">ARUBA</option><option value="AU">AUSTRALIA</option><option value="AT">AUSTRIA</option><option value="AZ">AZERBAIYÁN</option><option value="BS">BAHAMAS</option><option value="BH">BAHRÉIN</option><option value="XB">BANCO CENTRAL EUROPEO</option><option value="BD">BANGLADESH</option><option value="BB">BARBADOS</option><option value="BZ">BELICE</option><option value="BJ">BENÍN</option><option value="BM">BERMUDAS</option><option value="BY">BIELORRUSIA (BELARÚS)</option><option value="BO">BOLIVIA</option><option value="BA">BOSNIA-HERZEGOVINA</option><option value="BW">BOTSUANA</option><option value="BV">BOUVET, ISLA</option><option value="BR">BRASIL</option><option value="BN">BRUNÉI (BRUNÉI DARUSSALAM)</option><option value="BG">BULGARIA</option><option value="BF">BURKINA FASO (ALTO VOLTA)</option><option value="BI">BURUNDI</option><option value="BT">BUTÁN</option><option value="BE">BÉLGICA</option><option value="CV">CABO VERDE, REPÚBLICA DE</option><option value="KY">CAIMÁN, ISLAS</option><option value="KH">CAMBOYA</option><option value="CM">CAMERÚN</option><option value="CA">CANADÁ</option><option value="CF">CENTROAFRICANA, REPÚBLICA</option><option value="TD">CHAD</option><option value="CZ">CHECA, REPÚBLICA</option><option value="CL">CHILE</option><option value="CN">CHINA</option><option value="CY">CHIPRE</option><option value="CC">COCOS, ISLA DE (KEELING)</option><option value="CO">COLOMBIA</option><option value="KM">COMORAS (GRAN COMORA, ANJOUAN Y MOHéLI)</option><option value="CG">CONGO</option><option value="CD">CONGO, REPÚBLICA DEMOCRÁTICA DEL (ZAIRE)</option><option value="CK">COOK, ISLAS</option><option value="KP">COREA DEL NORTE (REPúBLICA POPULAR DEMOCRáTICA DE COREA)</option><option value="KR">COREA DEL SUR (REPúBLICA DE COREA)</option><option value="CI">COSTA DE MARFIL</option><option value="CR">COSTA RICA</option><option value="HR">CROACIA</option><option value="CU">CUBA</option><option value="DK">DINAMARCA</option><option value="DM">DOMINICA</option><option value="DO">DOMINICANA, REPÚBLICA</option><option value="EC">ECUADOR (INCLUIDAS LAS ISLAS GALáPAGOS)</option><option value="EG">EGIPTO</option><option value="AE">EMIRATOS ÁRABES UNIDOS (ABU DABI, DUBAI, SHARYA, AYMAN,</option><option value="ER">ERITREA</option><option value="SK">ESLOVAQUIA</option><option value="SI">ESLOVENIA</option><option value="ES">ESPAÑA</option><option value="US">ESTADOS UNIDOS DE AMÉRICA</option><option value="EE">ESTONIA</option><option value="ET">ETIOPÍA</option><option value="FO">FEROE, ISLAS</option><option value="PH">FILIPINAS</option><option value="FI">FINLANDIA (INCLUIDAS LAS ISLAS ALAND)</option><option value="FJ">FIYI</option><option value="FR">FRANCIA (INCLUIDOS LOS DEPARTAMENTOS FRANCESES DE ULTRAMAR:</option><option value="GA">GABÓN</option><option value="GM">GAMBIA</option><option value="GE">GEORGIA</option><option value="GS">GEORGIA DEL SUR Y LAS ISLAS SANDWICH DEL SUR</option><option value="GH">GHANA</option><option value="GI">GIBRALTAR</option><option value="GD">GRANADA (INCLUIDAS LAS ISLAS GRANADINAS DEL SUR)</option><option value="GR">GRECIA</option><option value="GL">GROENLANDIA</option><option value="GU">GUAM</option><option value="GT">GUATEMALA</option><option value="GG">GUERNESEY (ISLA ANGLONORMANDA DEL CANAL)</option><option value="GN">GUINEA</option><option value="GQ">GUINEA ECUATORIAL</option><option value="GW">GUINEA-BISSAU</option><option value="GY">GUYANA</option><option value="HT">HAITÍ</option><option value="HM">HEARD Y MCDONALD, ISLAS</option><option value="HN">HONDURAS (INCLUIDAS ISLAS DEL CISNE)</option><option value="HK">HONG-KONG</option><option value="HU">HUNGRIA</option><option value="IN">INDIA</option><option value="ID">INDONESIA</option><option value="XU">INSTITUCIONES DE LA UNIÓN EUROPEA</option><option value="IQ">IRAQ</option><option value="IE">IRLANDA</option><option value="IR">IRÁN</option><option value="IM">ISLA DE MAN</option><option value="IS">ISLANDIA</option><option value="IL">ISRAEL</option><option value="IT">ITALIA (INCLUIDO LIVIGNO)</option><option value="JM">JAMAICA</option><option value="JP">JAPÓN</option><option value="JE">JERSEY (ISLA ANGLONORMANDA DEL CANAI)</option><option value="JO">JORDANIA</option><option value="KZ">KAZAJSTÁN</option><option value="KE">KENIA</option><option value="KG">KIRGUISTÁN</option><option value="KI">KIRIBATI</option><option value="KW">KUWAIT</option><option value="LA">LAOS (LAO)</option><option value="LS">LESOTHO</option><option value="LV">LETONIA</option><option value="LR">LIBERIA</option><option value="LY">LIBIA</option><option value="LI">LIECHTENSTEIN</option><option value="LT">LITUANIA</option><option value="LU">LUXEMBURGO</option><option value="XG">LUXEMBURGO [POR LO QUE RESPECTA A LAS RENTAS PERCIBIDAS POR LAS SOCIEDADES</option><option value="LB">LÍBANO</option><option value="MO">MACAO</option><option value="MK">MACEDONIA (ANTIGUA REPúBLICA YUGOSLAVA)</option><option value="MG">MADAGASCAR</option><option value="MY">MALASIA (MALASIA PENINSULAR Y MALASIA ORIENTAL: SARAWAK, UMM AL-QAIWAIN, RA</option><option value="MW">MALAWI</option><option value="MV">MALDIVAS</option><option value="ML">MALI</option><option value="MT">MALTA (INCLUIDOS GOZO Y COMINO)</option><option value="FK">MALVINAS, ISLAS (FALKLANDS)</option><option value="MP">MARIANAS DEL NORTE, ISLAS</option><option value="MA">MARRUECOS</option><option value="MH">MARSHALL, ISLAS</option><option value="MU">MAURICIO [ISLAS MAURICIO, ISLAS RODRIGUES, ISLAS AGALEGA Y CARGADOS, CARAJO</option><option value="MR">MAURITANIA</option><option value="YT">MAYOTTE (GRAN TIERRA Y PAMANDZI)</option><option value="UM">MENORES ALEJADAS DE LOS EE.UU., ISLAS (BAKER, HOWLAND, JARVIS, JOHSTON, KIN</option><option value="MX">MEXICO</option><option value="MD">MOLDAVIA</option><option value="MN">MONGOLIA</option><option value="ME">MONTENEGRO</option><option value="MS">MONTSERRAT</option><option value="MZ">MOZAMBIQUE</option><option value="XN">ORGANISMOS INTERNACIONALES DISTINTOS DE LAS INSTITUCIONES DE LA UNIÓN EUROP</option><option value="QU">OTROS PAÍSES O TERRITORIOS NO RELACIONADOS</option><option value="PK">PAKISTÁN</option><option value="PW">PALAU</option><option value="PA">PANAMÁ (INCLUIDA LA ANTIGUA ZONA DEL CANAL)</option><option value="MM">MYANMAR (ANTIGUA BIRMANIA)</option><option value="MC">MÓNACO</option><option value="NA">NAMIBIA</option><option value="NR">NAURU</option><option value="CX">NAVIDAD, ISLA</option><option value="NP">NEPAL</option><option value="NI">NICARAGUA (INCLUIDAS LAS ISLAS DEL MAíZ)</option><option value="NG">NIGERIA</option><option value="NU">NIUE, ISLA</option><option value="NF">NORFOLK, ISLA</option><option value="NO">NORUEGA (INCLUIDAS LAS ISLAS LEALTAD: MARé, LIFOU Y OUVéA)</option><option value="NC">NUEVA CALEDONIA (INCLUIDAS LAS ISLAS LEALTAD: MARé, LIFOU Y OUVéA)</option><option value="NZ">NUEVA ZELANDA</option><option value="NE">NÍGER</option><option value="IO">OCÉANO INDICO, TERRITORIO BRITÁNICO DEL (ARCHIPIéLAGO  DE CHAGOS)</option><option value="OM">OMÁN</option><option value="XN">ORGANISMOS INTERNACIONALES DISTINTOS DE LAS INSTITUCIONES DE LA UNIÓN EUROP</option><option value="QU">OTROS PAÍSES O TERRITORIOS NO RELACIONADOS</option><option value="PK">PAKISTÁN</option><option value="PW">PALAU</option><option value="PA">PANAMÁ (INCLUIDA LA ANTIGUA ZONA DEL CANAL)</option></select>
```

Y [más info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10941789/where-is-jquery-sort-documentation) sobre `sort`

Comment: Entiendo que no haces uso de una base de datos ¿verdad? Seria lo unico que deberia cambiar en mi caso. Pruebo y lo comento

Comment: En mi caso tiramos de una base de datos DB2 a través de un webservice que es el que nos devuelve la lista de países. Una vez obtenidos los ordenamos con javascript y listo.

Answer (score 0):

Añade el tipo de ordenamiento en tu consulta, puedes ser ascendente o descendente DESC

```
$query = "SELECT idPais, nombre FROM traduccion WHERE idIdioma=".$_REQUEST["idioma"]." ORDER BY nombre ASC";
```

Esto te traerá todos los datos ordenados alfabéticamente.